# All products are gone

Tags: woocommerce

Just curious about a problem I had where I have wiped up all products in the woocommerce db.

I have executed the following query (which is incorrect, the ID in wp_postmeta does not exist).

```
delete from wp_posts where ID in (select ID from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_sku' and meta_value = 'XXXX');
```

but still it has not thrown any error and has removed all products.

Any ideas?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the point here is that the subquery by itself fails

Comment: Fair enough. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is the expected behaviour for the query above
when column in the subquery does not exist in the subquery table but it does on the main table.

Find the explanation here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218871/subquery-gives-no-error-for-a-non-existing-column-with-the-same-name-as-in-the-o